# flatMap is not a function, over an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, flatmap, ecmascript-2016

I am using Promise.all and await, to execute some promises. 
However I am getting the error 'flatMap is not a function'. I can see in the logs that the result is an Array, so flatMap operation should be allowed in an Array.

Could someone explain why could this be happening? Because I can find no explanation!!

Thanks

```
const groupIds = await userGroupRepository.getGroupsByUserId(userId);

    console.log('groupIds', groupIds);
    const promises = groupIds.map(groupId =>
      permissionGroupRepository.getPermissionsByGroupId(groupId),
    );

    console.log('promises', promises);

    const result = await Promise.all(promises);

    const isArr = Object.prototype.toString.call(result) == '[object Array]';

    console.log('isArray', isArr); // Logs true

    const permissions = result.flatMap(((r) => r)); // Error : flatMap is not a function
```

Comment: Why is there an additional parentheses? `flatMap(((r) => r))`

Comment: no browser. Node js app

Comment: @fgonzalez what Node version are you using?

Comment: What version of node? I believe it's only in node 11+

Comment: check feature availability https://node.green/

Comment: node version 8.10

Comment: Node 11.0.0 is the first version to support `.flatMap()`

Comment: Ok, I am running in a aws lambda, not sure if node 11 is supported. Otherwise I better forget of using flatMap. Thanks to all!